# An unhandled exception occured. on Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android

When starting my app I show the following error, and investigated about the error but I do not find answers in any forum xamarin, when I do the breakpoint this stops in the MainActivity.cs attached my code from now, thank you for you help
[image]

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace SITMovil.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SITMovil",
 Icon = "@drawable/icon",
 Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
 MainLauncher = true, 
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
                TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
           ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put a try catch in your OnCreate(Bundle bundle) method and catch what exception is there. Also you can try to put a event handler as AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException; See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58002/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-catch-all-unhandled-exceptions-on-xamarin-forms for details

Comment: The link to your error image is broken. Also, please add the error as text to your question because an image is more difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

Although It might not be helpful in given scenario but in my case when I was trying to load an icon that was not part of project, I got that exception.
Make sure you are not using resources that are no longer exist in the project.